# How to use useSelector inside tableUtils.jsx

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux, useselector

I couldn't able to use useSelector inside tableUtils.jsx file.

Tried accessing state value but end up in error.**React Hook "useSelector" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function.**

```
export const userDetails = useSelector((state) => state?.user?.userDetails);
```

This is how my utils.jsx files looks like

```
import { UserFilled, TrashCan } from '@carbon/icons-react';
const generateActionColumn = (item, deactivateStatus, auditTrialModal, classNames, deleteUser, onClickSendReminder) => (
  <div className="actionColumn" title={i18n.t('icons.rerenderUser')}>
    {item.status === classNames.invitedStatus ? (
      <Resend className="email" onClick={() => onClickSendReminder(item, true)} />
    ) : (
      <Resend className="email" style={{ visibility: 'hidden' }} />
    )}
    <span title={i18n.t('icons.deleteUser')}>
      <TrashCan className="delete icon_delete_user" onClick={() => deleteUser(item, true)} />
    </span>
    <OverflowMenu aria-label="overflow-menu" title={i18n.t('button.moreOptions')} flipped className="overflowMenuContainer">
      <OverflowMenuItem
        className={`tableDactivateButton ${
          item.status === classNames.registeredStatus
            ? classNames.deactiveClassname
            : item.status === classNames.deactivatedStatus
            ? classNames.activeClassname
            : ''
        }`}
        itemText={item.status === classNames.deactivatedStatus ? classNames.activateText : classNames.deactivateText}
        onClick={() => deactivateStatus(item, true)}
      />
      <OverflowMenuItem itemText={i18n.t('button.auditTrial')} onClick={() => auditTrialModal(item, true)} />
    </OverflowMenu>
  </div>
);
```

Want to use state value inside tableUtils.jsx (non react component)

Comment: can you share the full code for your component ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can not use the hooks outside a functional component. So that's why it is throwing the error. If you want to reuse the logic across different components, I suggest creating a custom hook.

```
const useTableUtils = () => { 
 const userDetails = useSelector((state) => state?.user?.userDetails);
 return {
       userDetails
   }
}
```

Inside the component use it like below

```
import {useTableUtils} from 'PATH_TO_ABOVE_FILE'

function YOUR_FUNCTIONAL_COMPONENT {

const { userDetails } = useTableUtils()

// Use the userDetails as you required 
}
```

You can re-use the above custom hook in other components as well.

Comment: Agree. I cannot use hooks outside a functional component. Inside tableUtils.jsx, I need to make use of the state using useSelector. tableUtils.jsx is not a functional component here

Comment: Yes. First, we should not keep the extension JSX for a util class. So as per your question, I understood that you are trying to reuse it across multiple components. So better to create custom hooks and use it.

Comment: Please see the updated question. Added my tableUtils.jsx file. Please help me here, how to use the state value in this file ?

Comment: I see. Yeah as per your file, you have only one place to add the useSelector which is inside the component defined.
`const generateActionColumn = (item, deactivateStatus, auditTrialModal, classNames, deleteUser, onClickSendReminder) => {

 const userDetails = useSelector((state) => state?.user?.userDetails);

// Added the hook above. Remaining will be as it is.
return <div className="actionColumn" title={i18n.t.....}</div>
}`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We have almost reached. But still am getting react hooks error. React Hook "useSelector" is called in function "generateActionColumn" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function.

Comment: Here we may have two issues. One is the functional component name. It should always start with a capital letter. So change it to `const GenerateActionColumn`. Second, instead of keeping so many parameters, add a single param called `props` and de-structure from it. It should be like const GenerateActionColumn = ({ item, deactivateStatus, auditTrialModal, classNames, deleteUser, onClickSendReminder }) => {
const userDetails = useSelector((state) => state?.user?.userDetails);
// Return your component
return <div> </div>
}

Comment: Nope @Gavara.Suneel. Stilll issue exist

Comment: Have you changed the component name? I mean kept the capital letter?

Comment: yeah Changed and tried. No luck

Comment: Hmm. Could you send me the updated code here?